# HTMLCollection[], how to reproduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So, running `document.getElementsByTagName('')` returns: `HTMLCollection[ ]`.

That is a weird notation because if we do `new function test() {}()`, it will return `test { }`.

However, if we do:

```
function test() { }
test.prototype = [];
var x = new test();
```

now calling `x` we get `Object[ ]`, how can we get `test[ ]` like `HTMLCollection[ ]`?


And do not even know what I would do with it (nothing probably), I'm just curious to know.
Thanks!

Comment: test is now an array. not like `HTMLCollection[ ]` or `test[ ]`.

Comment: Why do you bother making something work in JavaScript console only? The notation is just a formality; e.g. Chrome shows `[]`.

Comment: But `HTMLCollection` is not an Array (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)... Why is it treated as one?

Comment: `HTMLCollection` is a native construct that only native methods can return. You can create an array that becomes a `HTMLCollection`, it just can't be done.  `HTMLCollection` is an ***array-like*** object, which means it has length and can be iterated.

Comment: If you want to control how an object is represented in console you can change its `valueOf` like this `test.valueOf = function(){ return "test[ ]"; }`